# Delphi TBitmap - why are Pixels and ScanLine different?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, pixel, scanline

While using a 32 bit TBitmap, I switched from Canvas.Pixels to ScanLine.

I then set the value to Red, only to find it was displayed as blue.

Any idea why?

Here's a code excerpt:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  varBitmap: TBitmap;
  pLock: PIntegerArray;
  iColor: integer;
begin
  varBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  varBitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  varBitmap.Width := 800;
  varBitmap.Height := 600;

  // Set Pixels to Red
  varBitmap.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0] := $0000FF;

  // Shows $FF0000 (blue)
  pLock := varBitmap.ScanLine[0];
  iColor := pLock[0];
  ShowMessageFmt('%x', [iColor]);

  // Set ScanLine to Red
  pLock[0] := $0000FF;

  // Displays a blue pixel
  Canvas.Draw(0, 0, varBitmap);
end;
```

It seems that somehow TColor is not the same as what is in memory, but that makes no sense.

Any suggestions welcome. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

32bit pixel data is in `$AARRGGBB` format. You are setting the Blue component, not the Red component.  Use `$FF0000` instead of `$0000FF`. Or better, use the `RGB()` function.

Comment: SetPixel() uses 0x00bbggrr format while actual pixel data is opposite.

Comment: Ahhh, that would explain it. I had some custom fill function using clRed on the ScanLine, but I shouldn't use those TColor values anymore if I understand it correctly. I feel so old sometimes... Sigh.

Answer (score 6):

The VCL bitmap class, `TBitmap` is a wrapper around the Windows native device independent bitmap (DIB). These bitmap objects can store bitmaps in a wide variety of different pixel formats. They can be monochrome with a single bit per pixel, up to 32 bits per pixel, the format that you are using. They can also be used to store palette based bitmaps where each pixel holds an index into a color table.

The two methods of accessing the pixel data that you refer to are the `Pixels` property of `TCanvas` and the `ScanLine` property of `TBitmap`.

The `Pixels` property of `TCanvas` is a wrapper around the GDI [`GetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909.aspx) and [`SetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145078.aspx) functions. These is a high-level functions that operate on [`COLORREF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449.aspx) values. The documentation for [`COLORREF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449.aspx) says:

> The low-order byte contains a value for the relative intensity of red; the second byte contains a value for green; and the third byte contains a value for blue. The high-order byte must be zero. The maximum value for a single byte is 0xFF.

In other words, a `COLORREF` value has a fixed way of encoding the pixel color. The `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` functions much handle the transformation between the fixed `COLORREF` form and the underlying raw bitmap pixel data. Note also that a `COLORREF` cannot represent the alpha value. The `COLORREF` value is in $00BBGGRR format.

On the other hand, the `ScanLine` property of `TBitmap` returns you a pointer into the raw pixel data of the underlying DIB object. The data you work with here is 32bpp pixel data and the convention for that data is that it is stored in $AARRGGBB format. The Windows [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376.aspx) for 32bpp data says:

> The bitmap has a maximum of 2^32 colors. If the biCompression member of the BITMAPINFOHEADER is BI_RGB, the bmiColors member of BITMAPINFO is NULL. Each DWORD in the bitmap array represents the relative intensities of blue, green, and red for a pixel. The value for blue is in the least significant 8 bits, followed by 8 bits each for green and red. The high byte in each DWORD is not used.

So in fact this text is incorrect and out-of-date. The high byte in each `DWORD` is, in fact, the alpha channel, if it is used.

Comment: Thanks for explaining David. Sounds like they need to update the help file a bit. ;)

Comment: Yeah, it needs improvement. I wanted to try to explain things in a bit more detail here.